# does redux-query-sync enable sharing url between machines?

Tags: redux

I am trying to implement redux-query-sync but the url keeps going to default state if I share the url which has the updated state.

https://github.com/Treora/redux-query-sync/blob/master/src/redux-query-sync.js

I have implemented as shown in the sample - https://codesandbox.io/s/url-query-sync-qjt5f?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js

There is also a PropsRoute implementation in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be working for the `string` arguments.  It's the `array` param `selected` which is giving you trouble.

The action creator that you are dispatching here, `changeLocation`, does not take the right arguments.  Look at how you are calling it in your component:

```
changeLocation({
  location: event.target.name,
  checked: event.target.checked
});
```

When it is called from the URL query it is going to be called like:

```
changeLocation([Stockholm, Oslo]);
```

So obviously these do not match up.  The existing `changeLocation` action can only handle one location at a time, so there's not a way to map the `value` from the URL to a payload that you can use with it.  You will need to create a separate action.

```
const setLocation = (payload) => ({ type: "setLocation", payload });
```

```
case "setLocation":
  return {...state, selected: payload};
```

---

My first approach to handle the `array` values was to implement the optional `stringToValue` and `valueToString` settings for the `selected` param.

This only kinda-sorta works.  I can't get it to omit the param from the URL when it is set to the default value. I wonder if it's using a `===` check?  As a hacky solution, I added a `filter` in the `stringToValue` to prevent the empty string from getting added to the locations array.  But the `selected=` is always present in the URL.

```
selected: {
  selector: (state) => state.selected,
  action: setLocation,
  stringToValue: (string) => string.split(",").filter(s => !!s),
  valueToString: (value) => value.join(","),
  defaultValue: []
}
```

---

This really annoyed me, so I followed this bit of advice from the docs:

> Note you could equally well put the conversion to and from the string in the selector and action creator, respectively. The `defaultValue` should then of course be a string too.

And this approach worked much better.

```
selected: {
  selector: (state) => state.selected.join(","),
  action: (string) => setLocation(string.split(",")),
  defaultValue: ""
}
```

---

With those changes [you should have a shareable URL](https://j87ru.csb.app/?selected=Sala%2COslo&first=hello&last=world&type=dog).

[Forked Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/url-query-sync-forked-j87ru?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Linda. The example I sent was what I referred to do my implementation. It wasn't my work.

Just letting you know that since my app uses PropsRoute I was able to use `history` props to push the state as params in url and share the url. I had to modify code to use params from url as state if it was available. This worked between tabs. Will be testing across machines.

this.props.history.push("/currenturl/" + state)
this.props.history.push("/currenturl/" + {testobject:{}})

this.props.match.params.testobject

wasn't able to implement redux-query-sync though.